# Rendering strange in vscode terminal with oh my posh v3

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have optimized my terminal with oh-my-posh v3. It works fine in last vscode version and also in windows terminal, but seems strange in current vscode.

VS Code Terminal:

[image: vscode terminal]

Windows Terminal:

[image: windows terminal]

Anybody has this problem?

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I also tried to disable few seems related extensions to find any changes, but nothing. any idea?

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

1. Open VS Code Settings via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
2. Search for the item "Terminal > Integrated: Minimum Contrast Ratio"
3. Set the value to 1

[image: Integrated: Minimum Contrast Ratio]

### Explanation

VS Code v1.41 introduced the [minimum contrast ratio feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_minimum-contrast-ratio) where it dynamically changes the foreground of terminal text to meet a specified contrast ratio. However, in the latest update (v1.66), they changed to the default value to 4.5.

(Source: [GitHub issue #146406](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146406))

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your answer, my problem has been solved!!